# Solr indexing error - possible analysis error

Tags: solr, lucene

I just got an Solr 6.6.1 indexing error. Can you please help to figure out whether or nor this is a Solr defect? or is it just my configuration issue?

When I remove the stopword "pm", the indexing goes fine. I guess the stopword filter did something that makes the SynonymGraphFilter glitched.

**The value I used for indexing is** "Fridays:  7:00pm-11:30pm  Saturdays:  1:30pm-4:00pm and 7:00pm-11:30pm  Sundays".

**The schema I used**:

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="my_field" type="my_field_type" omitNorms="true" omitPositions="false" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" storeOffsetsWithPositions="true" stored="true" termVectors="false"/>

<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="my_field_type" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="0"
            stemEnglishPossessive="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Inside stopwords.txt:** pm

**Inside synonyms.txt:** qweasdzxc => abc

**The error message from Solr log**:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id 312310-003690 to the index; possible analysis error.
    at         org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:206)
at     org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:67)
at     org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:979)
at     org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1192)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:748)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:80)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:254)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:526)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:415)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:474)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:457)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.FlattenGraphFilter.releaseBufferedToken(FlattenGraphFilter.java:204)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.FlattenGraphFilter.incrementToken(FlattenGraphFilter.java:258)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymGraphFilter.parse(SynonymGraphFilter.java:332)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymGraphFilter.incrementToken(SynonymGraphFilter.java:199)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.FlattenGraphFilter.incrementToken(FlattenGraphFilter.java:268)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:746)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:447)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:403)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:232)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:478)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1571)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocument(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:924)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocOrDocValues(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:913)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:302)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:239)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:194)
... 16 more
```

Comment: I get the same exception on solr 7-4 (IndexOutOfBounds). I came across your question while researching on this. I'll tell you if I find something.

Comment: Eventually I decided to remove the use of flattengraphFilter, as I was not using synonyms. The problem dissappeared. Of course if you need synonyms it won't help!

Comment: Thank you @ HelloWorld. I made an workaround by changing the orignal text "Fridays: 7:00pm-11:30pm Saturdays: 1:30pm-4:00pm and 7:00pm-11:30pm Sundays"